# When i clicking the text area on my <form> tag there's a white square appearing on the top of the <form> tag

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

you can check the link so you can check what I'm trying to say.

and here is the code that I wrote. for that form. I did not style the .

https://kevkevkevin.github.io/contactform_/

```
<div id="form_">
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
          <form action="#">
             <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name:</label>
              <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" name="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subj"><span>Subject</span>
                    <select name="sbj" class="form-control" id="slct_bg">
                        <option class="special" value="Appointment">Appointment</option>
                        <option class="special" value="Interview">Interview</option>
                        <option class="special" value="Regarding a post">Regarding a post</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Message:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="message" placeholder="Leave your message here*" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <a href=""><div class="button_">
                Submit
            </div> </a>
          </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Doesn't happen for me on iPhone7

Comment: can you check on the desktop if possible :)

Comment: I checked and I don't see any white square. I'm on Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit with Google Chrome - Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: weird why I, seeing this thing on my end. BTW thanks a lo guys.

Comment: I don't see any white square also (Chrome), try to clear your cache